# How can I ensure that laptop batteries I buy are genuine?

Tags: battery

I need new batteries for my for MBP 2012 8.1 13". I ran across a site selling what seems to be actual new Apple batteries. Is this a scam? I would like to buy a real Apple product, so how can I be sure of this?

Comment: It's a scam.  Apple does not sell parts to third parties.  Therefore, anyone who claims to have them is either lying, or selling pulls.

Answer (score 1):

Some sellers offer batteries for MacBooks cheaper than Apple. If it is a well-known manufacturer or seller, I would have less to think about. However, I would order from a trusted shop.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be sure of getting a genuine Apple replacement battery is to take your MBP to an Apple Store or other Apple-certified technician. The 13" 2012 MBP was sold by Apple up to 2016, so it is therefore still a supported model.

If someone is selling something claiming to be a genuine Apple battery, then it is either:

1. Produced at the original factory Apple used as a 'run-on' (extra copies made beyond Apple's order); or batteries that didn't pass Apple's Quality Control.
2. A counterfeit product made at another factory that has been set up to produce similar products, complete with Apple-branding stickers. The quality standards will be unknown.

As a result, the quality will be a bit of lottery. There's no way to tell whether it will work well, or whether it lose capacity quickly, or expand, or catch fire ... ;-)

That having been said, I've bought several batteries from Chinese factory outlets on eBay for old Unibody MBPs, and they've worked well for a number of years.